# how to set color to share windows in android

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

My code :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"TEXT DEMO");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT DEMO");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"CHOOSE APP"));
```

It works well

**but the menu appears in white (as in picture 1) All I want to make the menu colour is black (as in picture 2).**

------ picture 1 ---------

[image: picture 1]

---

------ picture 2 ---------

[image: picture 2]

---

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system chooser dialog is from a separate system app. Its look and feel will be determined by the device manufacturer, and secondarily by Google (as the developers of Android). You do not have any control over the look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

If you post your code on where you set the colors probably I can help. But you should set it in the same way as you set the color of the second menu and it should work.